# How i use Rewrite Rules in PHP without nginx.conf or .htaccess

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I'm designing a website in PHP and I would like to work with rewrite rules. All the forums I look for say to edit nginx's configuration file or apache's htaccess file. How to use rewrite_rules in WordPress without editing anything on server?

Can you please reply with a working sample..

Comment: Wordpress uses .htaccess, it just creates the file but it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress does use a rewrite file if the function is enabled and available to the server, basically what the rewrite does it redirect all requests to a main index.php file which then based on the URL format you have configured depends on how the URL is handled.

https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess

Comment: so if i use nginx and i can access nginx.conf file what i have to do to add rewrite rules.. write an example please

Comment: @NikosGaLaTaS You can easily find examples of Nginx rewrites yourself in the [Nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html).